# How does electromagnetic radiation interact with materials such as rocks, soils, buried metal pipes

Tags: electromagnetism

In Ground Penetrating Radar geophysical surveys, Radar waves are transmitted into the ground and reflected back to the receiver. What is the interaction between the waves transmitted and the subsurface materials.

Comment: **What is the interaction** Can you be more specific, by asking  a question based on reading something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground-penetrating_radar

Answer (score 0):

Radio waves are made of photons just like visible light. When they're directed into the ground they can reflect off of objects the same as light.